# Different output when executing script manually and via cron/jenkins job

Tags: linux, shell-script, locale, character-encoding, sqlplus

I have a shell script which opens sqlplus and select some data from db containing chinese characters. When I execute it manually, the output contains those characters. When I do it via cron or jenkins job, it displays question marks instead of chinese characters. Any advice ?

Comment: The main point is to set up a cron or jenkins job to execute script periodicaly.

Comment: It could be an environmental variables issue.

Comment: have you read `man 5 crontab` ?

Comment: @RamanSailopal - Thanks it really was env variable issue, I just added $HOME/.bash_profile before main script in crontab and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enviroment variable issue. I just added **. $HOME/.bash_profile** beofre main script execution in crontab. 
`00 10 * * * . $HOME/.bash_profile; /home/scripts/script.sh`